# How to root Lenovo a660

Tags: rooting, lenovo-a660

I've tried rooting my phone by using SuperOneClick and RootWithRestore.

And did not have much success either. So my question is how to do this?
(*I checked that in `/system/bin` that I do not have the `su` binary in place!*)

Comment: Just for info: I placed your question on our [central rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/16575), as your device was not yet present there. You might check the methods mentioned there, maybe one of them is fitting for you.