# How can I root a Lenovo S660?

Tags: rooting, lenovo

I want to root Lenovo S660 and I came to know that Framaroot will help me in doing that; however, it doesn't work.

On [this site](http://androidxda.com/root-lenovo-s660) it says that
after installing framaroot click Boromir and it will pop up a SUCCESS dialog (the device is rooted). But it doesn't happen for me and the device does not get rooted.

What are Boromir, Faramir, and Barahir?

Comment: Those are most possibly three vulnerabilities known about your system. Each of them named as the ones you mentioned. If one vulnerability (name) doesn't work then try the other one.

Comment: related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37693/how-to-root-lenovo-a660/116513#116513